# Disabling spring cloud discovery on a running service

Tags: spring-cloud

I want to be able to stop discovery on a running service and potentially keep it from joining with eureka for an misbehaving service.  I can't see a specific property that will allow me to do this.

Basically a service is in the mix and causing issues and I want to have either a) the service stop registering to eureka or b) cancel a registration on eureka for a service.

Any ideas?

If it is not possible let me know and i will spin my own version of the discovery mechanism.

Comment: Do you want this to happen on startup or while running after starting?

Comment: after startup.  I understand that Hystrix can remove communication with the service on a temporary basis if failure, but say we want to do maintenance on a service while it is not being routed or accessed by other services.  So if it was possible to stop service renewal so that the service is isolated that would be the plan.  So after we are done our whatever, we could re-enable service registration.